# Typescript: Typeguard for many interfaces in the same function

Tags: typescript, typeguards, narrowing

In TS a type guard works like this:

```js
const isFoo = (x: any): x is Foo => {
  return (x as Foo).FooField !== undefined;
}
```

I have many interfaces, e.g. Foo, Bar, Baz. They all extend the same BaseInterface that has a `name` field.

```js
interface BaseInterface {
  name: 'string'
}

interface Foo extends BaseInterface {
  name: 'FOO'
}
...
```

Is there a way to create a generic type guard that works for all of these interfaces, based on the value of the name field?

Something like:

```js
const nameToType = {
  'FOO': Foo,
  'BAR': Bar,
  'BAZ': Baz
}

// As written, this doesn't work for a lot of reasons, such as
// mixing compile time and runtime data structures.
const genericTypeGuard = <T extends BaseInterface>(x: T): x is nameToType[x.name] {
  return nameToType[x.name]
}
```

---

ETA example use case with caching:

```js
// A config that allows selecting some data structures in the backend
// by key/value.
interface SelectByValue {
  name: 'SELECT_BY_VALUE'
  fieldKey: string
  value: string
}

interface ExpensiveSortArgs {
  name: 'EXPENSIVE_SORT_ARGS',
  selector: SelectByValue | SelectByContainer | ... 
  ...
}

interface ExpensiveSortResult {
  name: 'EXPENSIVE_SORT_RESULT',
  result: string[]
}

const runExpensiveSort = (args: ExpensiveSortArgs): ExpensiveSortResult => {
  const result = axios.post('/api/expensivesort', args as any);
  cache.storeResult('/api/expensivesort', args, result);
}
...
// inside cache.ts
const storeResult = (url: string, args: {[key: string]: any}, result: any) => {
  if (args?.selector?.name === 'SELECT_BY_VALUE') {
    // add specific other invalidation keys to the cache
  }

  cache.write(url, hash(args), result)
}
```

in the above example, TS will fail on the `args.selector` line because it doesn't think that args has the field `selector`. I would like to typeguard that structure. One way to do this is to write many different typeguards, but I'm hoping that there is some way to exploit the fact that all of my interfaces have a similar identifier (i.e. the `name` field)

Comment: How would you use such a thing?  I could imagine `if (genericTypeGuard(x, "BAR")) { x.someBarProperty }` but I have no idea what `if (genericTypeGuard(x)) { }` by itself would do.  Could you provide a [mre] including some definitions for your multiple interfaces (presumably they have more than just the `name` property, otherwise why bother narrowing) and how you intend to use your type guard function?

Comment: Also, `'string'` is a typo, right?  Could you test your example in an IDE and make sure that it demonstrates your issue and only your issue?

Comment: I fiddled a bit with this, but didn't get very far. I don't think this particular mix of compile time and runtime (types/values) can be wrangled to work; you're probably better off simply copypasting your type guards.

Comment: Here's the fiddle that I got.
[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QJLmvJZAbwChlkQ4BbCALmQHIAxAeRYeQB9HUBBAJQ7cGfAFoMA3CQC+JUJFiIUTAPYrkEAB6QQAEwxpMOPIsKlylGvWZsGMuSYIp0UDdoh6D6LLgVPiZBTUdDwCdrLy+EqGAF5uOvqGPo7R5kFWoeL2kaYoALJwAA4sMAAqAJ6FEAZpNuz0qioANIEiYfQuLeRt4h1wMfYkCCogGGDIAOYe0MAIFVUA4gCucFC6yAC8yAA8pfEeid7GfkoAfAAUmvSlAJT0msjABgXFZZXVANqaAHSWEAC65A2p2IyAA9GDkGAoOVQBMoeollhkAA3OAAGyWKEwyDgUPegSgEDASygIHBkIA-NSoTC4QjkEiUGB3riDHi0ZiIN8eYNhqNxpysX1kidCFsiOkQj0ONIpHIYMhzlMQDM5u9lqtdOchRAbjcAuQZEA)

Comment: @jcalz i added an example, hopefully this helps get the idea across. In particular use case, I also have a large enum with the strings that uniquely identify each structure in my application. I would like to condition on that enum to get typescript to understand the type, especially at, say, socket interfaces or db interfaces where all I know at runtime is 'I got a JSON response'.

Comment: Please modify your code into a self-contained [mre] that others could paste into a standalone IDE (like [the TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wye8dW)) and quickly demonstrate for themselves the issue you're seeing and only that issue.  Pseudocode, undeclared types and values, and external dependencies only make this more difficult.

Comment: Besides of providing a minimal reproducible example, you may take advantage of `axios` types, i. e. you could call `const result = axios.post<ExpensiveSortArgs, ExpensiveSortResult>('/api/expensivesort', args);`. Maybe the generic type guard could be obsolete.